# Will advanced filter for full page url view affect older data?

Tags: url, google-analytics

I need to see full urls in my Analytics. If I use advanced filter (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en), will it affect also my older data? It would be large complication if it analysed shortened and full urls separately after apllying the filter. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters only start working from when they are applied, not on "old data", or data you have in your current account. It does not work retroactively.

So, yes, it would be a large complication because say you have `www.domain.com/startpage`, it'd currently show up as `/startpage`. Once the filter is applied, it'd show up as `www.domain.com/startpage`. You would now have two different rows for the same URI.